# How to expose a web app on a kubeadm cluster?

Tags: web-applications, kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

How can I expose a web app running inside a Docker container on a Kubernetes cluster created with `kubeadm`? I want to be able to access the application on an IP address using a regular port (80 or 443). I have tried:

```
kubectl expose deployments/mywebsite --type=NodePort --port=80
```

but I can only access it over a high port number.

Using `--type=LoadBalancer`, but the external IP stays on `Pending`.

Is there a way to make my web app accessible over an IP and low port on my custom cluster?

Comment: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/ Just read this article and you will come up with a right answer!

Comment: @IvanAracki Thanks! This article helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running Kubernetes cluster on aws or cloud provider? If not you cant used service type load balancer then.

Exposing on nodeport should be Ok and it will allocate a high random port in that 30k-32k range on cluster node.

To use a low port such as 80 , point your external load balancer to Kubernetes nodePort service.

User port 80 on your external load balancer such nginx or apache

You can also use an ingress controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, no, I'm running my cluster on bare-metal and not AWS or a cloud provider. I was able to use NodePort, however I wanted to use specify a low port. How can I setup an external load balancer?

Comment: yes , then use a nodeport. run apache or nginx as separate service listening on port 80 , that will proxy the traffic to your nodeport

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of that. I assume that would be outside the cluster then? Is there a way to still manage the load balancer with Kubernetes?

Comment: yes , you can run nginx on kubernetes as separate deployment

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: i would recommend to install the ingress-nginx controller (https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)  on your k8s cluster and install a nginx as a loadbalancer. so you can forward the traffic on your api to the defined nodes and matching hostports. (https://dasunhegoda.com/nginx-reverse-proxying-load-balancing/1248/)